# SQL Server Express Idle Timeout Period?

Tags: sql-server, timeout, sql-server-express

I am using SQL Server Express 2012 for an ASP.NET application, and I noticed that if no one had used the site for more than 20 minutes or so then the first time a page hit the DB it would take more than 10 seconds to load, with subsequent hits to the DB being fast. I looked at the event log and discovered that SQL Server was being woken up by the page hit. I created a command line application that does a simple query to the DB and set it to run in the task manager every 20 minutes. Then I still noticed the "wakeup" entry like this every 20 minutes:

> Server resumed execution after being idle 193 seconds: user activity
>   awakened the server. This is an informational message only. No user
>   action is required.

Most of the time it was exactly 193 seconds, with a few saying 183 and even one time it said 173 seconds. I don't know why they all seem to end in 3, but this makes me believe there is a timeout after about 1000 seconds of inactivity. My questions:

1. Is this timeout only for SQL Server Express?
2. Is the length of the timeout documented anywhere? If yes, does it differ between 2008 and 2012?

Answer (score 3):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/02/22/sql-express-behaviors-idle-time-resources-usage-auto-close-and-user-instances.aspx

According to this you can't change this feature in sql server express

"this behavior change is unique to SQL Express, if you have need for your SQL Server to stay awake, SQL Workgroup or higher would be a more appropriate choice for your database engine."

Comment: I came across this question again trying to find the documented timeout for SQL Server Express 2012 and 2014. Sure would be nice if MS told us...